# Was Joseph a prophet?

Tags: genesis, prophets, joseph

His ability to correctly interpret dreams which foretold the future (in Genesis 40-41) suggests the answer is "yes." But the fact that, unlike the patriarchs, God is never once recorded as having spoken to Joseph (in Gen 37-50) suggests the answer is "no." What is the normal view, and what is the correct view?

Comment: How do *you* define "prophet"? Why don't dreams from God count as God speaking to Joseph?

Comment: Wouldn't that be part of the question to answer?

Comment: If it's left to answers to give such definitions, then the answers will all just be opinions, which we don't do here. Instead of that, we like questions to provide clear criteria, which can then be evaluated against an individual in the answers.

Comment: But then people would just debate my definition, and rightly so. By specifying a definition in advance, I would probably invite complaints about it, from some parties. This is a naturally open-ended question and proper Bible scholars ought to be able to deal with it as such. Many questions of biblical theology will strike some as "just opinion," right?

Comment: No, we don't allow debates like that here. If someone has a competing definition of prophet they can ask their own questions about it. Alternatively you could specify whose answer you want, such as Catholicism, LDS, Baptist, etc, and then they can give an answer explaining how their denominations understands the role of a prophet and whether Joseph would qualify.

Comment: You might find it helpful to read [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: One could say that Joseph was a 'seer'.

Comment: Just returning to this exchange after a few months. "We don't allow debates like that here." This forum's topic is mainly Christian theology. You surely allow debates over theology? And what "prophet" means is a question of (what else?) biblical theology. So if you really do have a policy that that questions must stipulate a definition that everyone must follow in their answers, this strikes me as a rather obviously bad policy, and you really ought to reconsider it. But perhaps I'm still not understanding. I did read the policy page—it seems to support me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to answer this only going off what you have said and attempting to derive a definition of prophet from your statements.

You seem to imply that prophet requires a person to a) receive revelation to future events from God and b) state those events to others. I think that's a fine definition.

But Joseph fits that definition. He receives dreams concerning future events from God, and tells those dreams to others.

Genesis 37:5-8:

> 5 Now Joseph had a dream, and when he told it to his brothers they hated him even more. 6 He said to them, “Hear this dream that I have dreamed: 7 Behold, we were binding sheaves in the field, and behold, my sheaf arose and stood upright. And behold, your sheaves gathered around it and bowed down to my sheaf.” 8 His brothers said to him, “Are you indeed to reign over us? Or are you indeed to rule over us?” So they hated him even more for his dreams and for his words. (ESV)

These verses foretell of the brothers bowing down to Jospeh later in the narrative.

So, yes, Joseph was a prophet.

Comment: It was the Pharaoh who saw the dreams, not Joseph. The Pharaoh was not able to interpret them, and  took the help of Joseph.  Of course, both the dreams and  their interpretation were God-driven messages for future.    Joseph's status as a Hebrew prisoner would have stood in the way of   ` action 'had he seen the dreams himself. So, he takes credit jointly with the Pharaoh for saving Egypt from  7 years'famine .  One doubts if that makes him fit to be named a prophet.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Joseph received dreams in his childhood, such as the stocks of wheat

Comment: Can you quote the text, please ?

Comment: Genesis 37:5-8 (ESV) 5 Now Joseph had a dream, and when he told it to his brothers they hated him even more. 6 He said to them, “Hear this dream that I have dreamed: 7 Behold, we were binding sheaves in the field, and behold, my sheaf arose and stood upright. And behold, your sheaves gathered around it and bowed down to my sheaf.” 8 His brothers said to him, “Are you indeed to reign over us? Or are you indeed to rule over us?” So they hated him even more for his dreams and for his words. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Luke Hill, that dream of Joseph meant that he would someday become his brothers' master.  And he did, even if the brothers had tried to get rid of him.  The dream as such, had nothing to do with the famine that would later fall on Egypt. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan I believe you are correct, but it still entails a prophetic aspect. The clear implication is that God gave Joseph this dream of future events.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph has two dreams and Pharaoh has two dreams. In both cases they have to rely on God to interpret their dreams. God does so for Pharaoh through Joseph but He does not do this for Joseph. He allows time and providence to tell him exactly what his dreams meant. That is, Pharoah finds out what his dreams mean before they are fulfilled and Joseph finds out what his dreams meant after or as they are fulfilled. Joseph could only guess at the strong hint given by God in his dreams but there was no way of knowing exactly what they meant. The focus in Joseph's life was not that he had a career in dreams and interpretation but that he was faithful and the person God chose to use to provide and preserve His people. So, no, I would not consider Joseph a prophet but one endowed with a gift to interpret dreams.